# JSON to append in Big Query CLI using write_disposition=writeAppend fails

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I could not make BQ shell to append JSON file using the keyword --write_disposition=WRITE_APPEND.

```
load --sour_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --write_disposition=WRITE_APPEND dataset.tablename /home/file1/one.log /home/file1/jschema.json
```

I have file named one.log and its schema jschema.json.

While executing the script, it says

```
FATAL flags parsing error : unknown command line flag 'write_dispostion'
RUN 'bq.py help' to get help.
```

I believe Big query is append only mode, there should be possibility of appending data in table, I am unable to get workaround, any assistance please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the default operational mode is WRITE_APPEND using the BQ tool. 
And there is no --write_disposition switch for the BQ shell utility.

But there is a `--replace` should set the write_disposition to truncate.

Comment: Yes , replace switch works perfectly for truncate, if WRITE_APPEND is by default, let me check without any flags and get back.